# How to break the html page in different section?

Tags: javascript, html

i am using two div tags in page (i.e) one on left and another on right like book.
now i am load html page in left side, if it exceed then it goto right side of the div tag.
give me an idea to implement this.

Thank you for looking

Comment: Can you show us the HTML / CSS / JavaScript you already have or and example on http://jsfiddle.net/ and a clear idea of what your problem is ....

Comment: Idea: Compute the lefts sides height, compute the contents height, iterate over the content elements and take as many such that `content.height <= leftSide.height` and add them to the left side. Add the rest to the right side.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, CSS3, You can use Multi column layout with Height specified in css class.

```
            <html>
            <head>Test </head>

            <style>
            .tt{
                 -moz-column-count: 2;
                 -moz-column-gap: 1em; 
                 -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black; 
                 -webkit-column-count: 2;
                 -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
                 -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
                 height:200px;
            }

            </style>
            <body>
            <div class="tt">
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. 
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. 
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. 
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. 
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. 
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. 
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. 
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.     
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived. HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.     
                HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.HTML5 and CSS3 have just arrived.     
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I'm not Microsoft fan. so no promise for IE.

Comment: Don't use only webkit- and moz-prefixes, Opera supports this too ([without prefix](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto29/css/multicolumnlayout/)).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you want a two-column presentation where the text continues from the bottom of the first column to the start of the second column. Although Netscape had a proprietary tag for such purposes, it wasn’t used much, and it died with Netscape. The issue is regarded as styling and part of [CSS3 Multicolumn Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/) module. The main problem with it is lack of support in any version of IE. For an introductory article, check out [Columns](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html) at QuirksMode.org.